# IntelliJ 2022.1 does not stop terminal processes for npm run configurations anymore

Tags: intellij-idea

after updating IntelliJ to 2022.1 the npm terminal tasks are not stopping anymore.

i.e. when I press the stop icon (or press CTRL-F2), the process keeps running. In the terminal I see:

```
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

[image]

to really stop the process, we can answer the question in the terminal with Y or press Stop again.

Is this a regression or is there something else, that I am missing.

A related annoyance is that IntelliJ will hang when we close it, if such a process is still waiting for the terminate question to be answered.

Comment: Do you face this issue with npm tasks only?

Comment: I guess it affects all run configs that open a terminal. E.g. docker run configs still work (but they don't open a terminal), Shell script configs open a terminal, but they don't show up in the Services tab or in the stop dialog (so can anyway only be stopped by using CTRL-C in the terminal window).

Comment: I've created a bugreport : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293103/IntelliJ-2022.1-does-not-stop-terminal-processes-for-npm-run-con

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug WEB-55423](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55423/Processes-are-not-killed-and-hang-indefinitely-when-running-NPM-scripts-if-using-NPM-binary-as-a-package-manager) that has been fixed in version 2022.1.1